# Count the rows with consecutive time periods in R

Tags: r, count, timestamp, sequence

I have a large file of timestamp data, which looks as follows. The dataset covers date and Time in increments of 1 minute. A small subset of the data frame looks like:

```
Date <- c("03/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "03/06/2019")

Time <- c("17:15:00","17:16:00", "17:17:00", "17:21:00", "17:22:00", "17:25:00", "17:26:00", "17:28:00")

idleness <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df1 <- data.frame(Date, Time, idleness)
```

Then I convert all the Time values of the data frame into 'times' data type.

```
df1$Time <- chron(times = df1$Time)
```

I want to produce a graph to look at minutes of continuous idle (one, two, three min etc) vs counts (how many clumps of consecutive idle minutes).

All time values are in 1-minute intervals. When this flow of 1-minute iterations is disrupted (after 17:17:00, it is not stamped at 17:18:00 hence it is disrupted), it should count the next timestamp as the start of a new consecutive time flow and again calculate the number of rows until this flow is disrupted again.
For example in the example data frame, there's only one, 3-minute idle period (17:15:00","17:16:00", "17:17:00"), two 2-minutes idle periods ("17:21:00", "17:22:00" and "17:25:00", "17:26:00") and only one 1-minute idele period ("17:28:00").

Hence the output I expect should look like this:

| Continuous Idle Minutes | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 min | 1 |
| 2 min | 2 |
| 3 min | 1 |

I hope all is clear - if not, I'd be happy to clarify it further. Thank you very much in advance.
I would be grateful if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: you define `idleness` and then use `x`, typo?

Comment: Is this time-of-day or a true timestamp? Is there a reason you're ignoring `Date`? What do consecutive rows with `23:59:00` and `00:03:00` produce? (If `Date` is relevant there, how does that change things?)

Comment: Thanks I corrected the typo. The original data set contain these time values for each day. But my intention is to examine the idleness for each day separately.

Comment: Okay, then it seems that you should not be using `chron` to produce time-of-day, instead you should be generating true timestamps (perhaps with `as.POSIXct`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
df1$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(df1$Date, df1$Time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df1$grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df1$timestamp) != 1))
df1
#         Date     Time idleness           timestamp grp
# 1 03/06/2019 17:15:00        1 2019-03-06 17:15:00   1
# 2 03/06/2019 17:16:00        1 2019-03-06 17:16:00   1
# 3 03/06/2019 17:17:00        1 2019-03-06 17:17:00   1
# 4 03/06/2019 17:21:00        1 2019-03-06 17:21:00   2
# 5 03/06/2019 17:22:00        1 2019-03-06 17:22:00   2
# 6 03/06/2019 17:25:00        1 2019-03-06 17:25:00   3
# 7 03/06/2019 17:26:00        1 2019-03-06 17:26:00   3
# 8 03/06/2019 17:28:00        1 2019-03-06 17:28:00   4
df2 <- aggregate(timestamp ~ grp, data = df1, FUN = function(z) as.numeric(diff(range(z)), units = "mins"))
df2
#   grp timestamp
# 1   1         2
# 2   2         1
# 3   3         1
# 4   4         0
table(df2$timestamp)
# 0 1 2 
# 1 2 1
```

where the `0 1 2` (which are strings) are the number of minutes, and the `1 2 1` are the number of times that gap-minutes occurred.

The last is `0` because the `17:28:00` is by itself, so its `range` is 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I knwo in df2, why it says there are 2 timestamps with grp 1? Can you explain that a little bit?

Comment: `17:21` to `17:22` is one minute. `17:25` to `17:26` is one minute. Two "1"s. If you want that to mean 2 instead, then just add one, since all "gaps" will be the same: deficient by one.

Comment: Sorry I got another question. My original data frame contains data for multiple days as well. As my intention is to analyze the idleness for each day, how am I supposed to use group by function here to group into different days as well?

Comment: If you're using `dplyr`, then `%>% group_by(Date)` should work. If you're needing grouping and are not otherwise using `dplyr`, then you can add `Date` to the grouping with `aggregate(timestamp ~ Date + grp, ...)`.

Comment: If you're using `dplyr`, then you likely shouldn't be using `aggregate`; it can work, but it would make more sense to do something like `df1 %>% group_by(Date, grp) %>% summarize(d = as.numeric(diff(range(timestamp)), units = "mins"))`